# fastlane generates unsigned apk file

Tags: android, fastlane, crashlytics-android

I am quite new to android and fastlane. I have integrated fastlane in my project following it's [documentation](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/beta-deployment/) but whenever I run `bundle exec fastlane beta` I get error

> Crashlytics halted compilation because it can't distribute the unsigned APK: /Users/umair/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectTest/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am also attaching my Fastfile probably something wrong over there.

Note that: I am able to generate signed apk from android studio. Problem seems only with fastlane perhaps. I have also added `signingconfig` in `build.gradle` file.

```
fastlane_version "2.68.0"
generated_fastfile_id "<fast file id here>"

default_platform :android

lane :beta do

  gradle(task: "clean")
  gradle(
    task: 'assemble',
    build_type: 'Release'
  )

  crashlytics(

    api_token: "<api token here>",
    build_secret: "<build secret here>"
  )
end
```

Appreciate your help please. :)